# How to set up a webhook in Telegram bot

Tags: ssl, nginx, telegram-bot

I can not connect the webhook telegram. Installed the certificate "let's encrypt" ssl https://tele.velasoft.kz/

nginx settings https://gist.github.com/Asetss/99575e15ffee96c53cc6d7e2cf543eb2

Did so

```
curl -F "url=https://tele.velasoft.kz/botman/" -F "certificate=/var/ssl/telebot.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook
```

and

```
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setWebhook?url=https://tele.velasoft.kz/botman
```

All the time returns

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `botTOKEN` with your own token, looks like `bot109780439:AAJqs_w-4`

> Use the /newbot command to create a new bot. The Bot Father will ask you for a name and username, then generate an authorization token for your new bot.

Ref: [Frequently Asked Questions](http://telegra.ph/Awesome-Telegram-Bot-11-11)

Comment: Thanks.Only changed the token and earned